# Adding New Row With Form Elements & A PHP Value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table that when a button is pressed it adds a new row.  Here it is:

```
<table id='editTable' width='655' border='1'>";
<tr><th width='330' align='left'>Expense Description</th><th width='100'>Cost</th></tr>

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID,TASK_ID,EXPENSE_DESC,EXPENSE_COST FROM b_report_expense2 WHERE TASK_ID = $taskid AND REF = $referenceID");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$expenseDesc = $row['EXPENSE_DESC'];
$expenseCost = $row['EXPENSE_COST'];
$exID = $row['ID'];
<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='ref[]' value='$exID' /><input type='text' name='expense[]' value='$expenseDesc'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='expensecost[]' value='$expenseCost'></td></tr>
}

<tr><td colspan='2'><button class='no-style-button' type='button' onclick='displayResult2()'>Add Row</button><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></td></tr></table>
```

When the add new row button is pressed it adds a new row fine however it doesn't recognise $exID as the value in the loop.  Here's the javascript:

```
function displayResult2()
{
var table=document.getElementById("editTable");
var row=table.insertRow(1);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML= "<input size='5' type='hidden' name='refID' value='$referenceID' style='padding:2px;'/><input type='text' name='expenseaddition[]' style='padding:2px;' size='80'>";
cell2.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='expensecostaddition[]' style='padding:2px;' size='6'>";
}
```

The new row gets added to the top of the table above the other rows.  Now the issue lies that $referenceID is not being recognised in the javascript.  The page is declaring it that the new row is added to but it's not recognising it.  This javascript is being called from an external file to the page, is this the issue?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say *"This javascript is being called from an external file to the page"* do you mean like a `<script>`-tag on the page?

Comment: <script src="location" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PHP is *server-side* while the JS is *client-side*. This means that the JS gets executed after the page has been served to the user. Because PHP variables only exist on the server, the JS literally inserts `$referenceID` as a string.

To work around this, you could output the value of `$referenceID` to JS var:

```
<script>
 var referenceID = <?php echo $referenceID?>; //If $referenceID isn't a numeric value, remember to use quotes (`'<?php echo $referenceID?>'`)
</script>
<!--Then include your JS-->
<script src="location" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In that way you could get `referenceID` by doing:

```
cell1.innerHTML= "<input size='5' type='hidden' name='refID' value='"referenceID"' style='padding:2px;'/><input type='text' name='expenseaddition[]' style='padding:2px;' size='80'>";
```

Comment: I thought this prior to your post but thank you and it's now working :-)

Comment: Sorry, that should really say beat me to it!